# Book identification: a planet of poisonous plants where people live in the tops of trees

Tags: story-identification

I remember the main character was on an alien planet where people lived in the tops of the trees. Almost all the plants were poisonous. There were levels, and the lower the level, the more deadly the level was. Also, I think you had to be introduced to the home tree or it would kill you. A corporation was exploiting the planet for new pharmaceuticals. In one scene, there were some ant-like animals that would go on a march and kill everything in their path. If you can help me identify this story, I'll be thrilled.

Comment: The trees made me think of [The Integral Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Integral_Trees), but I don't think the rest of it fits.

Comment: Definitely not The Integral Trees, which isn't even set on a planet.

Comment: Sounds very Deathworld-esque - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deathworld

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67567/ya-trilogy-written-in-80s-90s (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 14):

Midworld by Alan Dean Foster had some similarities to this. Very old though, so depends when you came across it.

Been a long time since I read it so this is really what jogged loose when looking it up again on Amazon and wikipedia.

The entire planet is arboreal and extremely hostile. The indigenes are descendants of a spaceship that crashlanded or something a long time ago and have adapted to the local environment developing psychic links with symbiotic animals (ish) that are vaguely ursine.

A hunter discovers a ship from 'civilization' that has come down looking for exploitable plants, and starts of helping them but then changes his mind when he discovers they are there with an exploitative agenda.

A very good book in its time, but definitely the more pulp side of the genre. Published in the 70's.

[Amazon link - reviews at the bottom](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Midworld-Orbit-Books-Alan-Foster/dp/0708880096)

[Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midworld)

Comment: It'd be great if you could explain some of the similarities or at least identify the date the book was published. It would help figure out if it is the same book.

Comment: The 70s qualify as "very old" now? Get off my lawn kid :)

Comment: It's worth noting that the world in question (Midworld) has been featured in several of Foster's more recent books. It was visited in several of the Flinx series books, and also played an important part in the story arc of said series.

Comment: This is definitely Midworld. I've read it a few times, and the synopsis by the OP is almost word for word in the way I'd describe it. Home tree and all.

Comment: I agree it's Midworld.