# Book series about an orphan befriending a dragon and traveling between stars

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, spaceship, parallel-universe, dragons

In my early years, I read a book about a orphan boy with strange colored eyes found on a off-planet world and raised, for some reason, I keep thinking his name is Fix although this may be incorrect. He be-friends/bonds with a small dragon (Dragon pixie?) type character whilst growing up.

As the series progresses, he travels planets and actually due to light speed travel, he technically moves into the future without ageing very much in a ship with fully automated AI, designed by a race which he helped save?

I'm sorry I cannot remember more, this was at least 11 years ago, I recall there were many books in the series and he was seen as a prophesied one who was going to save the universe.

The last book ended in the main character saying 'I'm Bored'

Comment: "and raised, for some reason" - there seems to be a missing sentence here :)

Comment: I think it's supposed to be "and raised. For some reason, I keep thinking..."

Answer (score 11):

Allen Dean Foster's [Pip and Flinx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flinx) books, part of the "[Humanx Commonwealth](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/HumanxCommonwealth)" books.

> Flinx was born 533 A.A (2933 A.D) in Allahabad, India, on Terra. Flinx was born to a high-end prostitute named Rud Anasage Lynx (the last part Lynx is a title for her form of prostitute, not a last name.) She was approximately age 22. It was recorded that Flinx had unusual R-wave activity in his brain at birth that was noted as indicating potential or possible abnormal class one talent. However, the Anasage was not his "mother" in the conventional sense, nor did he have a "father." As revealed by Anayabi in Patrimony, both the paternal and maternal genetic material was combined from base elements, "a strand of protein here, a fragment of nucleic acid there," before being inserted into Anasage; Flinx was one of many experiments by a group known as the Meliorare Society, though Skua September admitted donating genetic material to the Meliorares when a similarity between Flinx and himself was noted.
>
> Flinx together with several other "experiments" was raised in several locations, constantly being relocated to avoid the authorities, who eventually overpowered many of the renegade engineers and reclaimed the children. Flinx was evaluated as normal, and deposited in a slaver market where, at the age of eight, he was bought by Mother Mastiff and thereafter raised in a lower class section of Drallar on the planet Moth. Mother Mastiff practiced a variety of scams, often aimed at tourists, and Flinx followed in her footsteps becoming a minor thief. Early on, Flinx discovered that he had a quite erratic and uncontrollable empathic (i.e. sensing another's emotions) ability. He came across and was befriended by an Alaspinian minidragon in an alley during his wanderings around Drallar; he named the minidrag "Pip" and it become his closest companion.

And yes, the fourteenth book, *[Flinx Transcendent](https://books.google.com/books?id=Qm8QnTbOTAgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22flinx%20transcendent%22%20bored&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjctrDYgNDYAhVK11MKHStNBxYQ6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=bored&f=false)* ends with the following line by Flinx:

> "I'm — bored."

Comment: If this is correct, don't forget to accept by clicking the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: And if so, probably a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67567/ya-trilogy-written-in-80s-90s/67569#67569