# Book: World covered in trees that are miles high

Tags: story-identification, books

The world is covered in trees that are miles high. A resident of the planet climbs to the highest tree top to find a crashed ship. He has never been to that level before. This leads him on a journey to the lowest depths which no one has seen before, which is full of strange creatures. I think the cover showed the resident climbing down into the dark lower areas with tree roots and glowing creatures.

It was a very small book, and a very quick read. I stayed up all night to finish it. I borrowed it from a friend who was into Dune in about 1986.

Comment: Do you remember the book's cover picture? When did you read it? Any more details would help

Comment: do not remember the cover. it was a very small book. very quick read. stayed up all night and finished it. borrowed from a friend who was into Dune about 1986. he really loved it also.

Comment: take it back, i think the cover showed the resident climbing down into the dark lower areas with the tree roots and glowing creatures.

Comment: Obviously, the planet is Kashyyk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [YA Trilogy written in 80's/90's](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67567/ya-trilogy-written-in-80s-90s)

Comment: @Otis Same series but unless I'm missing something it appears to be a different book in the series.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I believe it is *Midworld* by Alan Dean Foster. 
[image]
Wikipedia:

> Midworld is a planet entirely covered by a rain forest three-quarters of a kilometer (almost half a mile) tall. Born is a member of the primitive human society that has lived peacefully on Midworld for hundreds of years, careful not to disturb the natural balance of the jungle. His people live in a gigantic tree called the Home Tree. When they die, they are ceremonially buried in another gigantic tree of a species called They-Who-Keep. Each of the locals forms a lifetime bond with a powerful and intelligent photosynthetic animal called a furcot. When they need to damage a plant they are familiar with, they communicate with it empathetically ("emfoling") to make sure it does not object.
>
> The world is disrupted by the arrival of an exploitative business venture from Earth whose representatives know nothing of the delicate stability of the planet. A man and a woman from this company crash in their aircraft near Born's home. He, a fellow hunter named Losting (both hunters are in love with the tribe's most beautiful girl), and their furcots lead the castaways safely through the jungle's surprising dangers to their station.
>
> Born realizes that the newcomers are on his world to gain a life-extending drug from the burls formed by the They-Who-Keep trees around buried people. Horrified by this discovery and the invaders' callousness toward living beings, he uses native plants and animals to destroy their station. In the final fight Losting is killed, but Born returns to the Home Tree. Losting's brain and mind are absorbed to form part of a developing planet-wide network of consciousness involving They-Who-Keep and the furcots.

Other books with giant forests are *Hothouse* by Brian Aldiss and *Earth in Twilight* by Doris Piserchia.

Comment: i remember the 2nd book cover. i think this is it. i remember the main character being named born.

Comment: verified, this is the book. this means a lot to me. thank you

Comment: Wow, story is a lot like the movie Avatar.

Comment: There was also a novella or serialized novel published in *Analog* magazine in the 1980s, titled (in that form), "Class Six Climb" about climbing a tree (cover illustration made it look like a redwood or sequoia) that stood multiple kilometers tall.  Absolutely not the book the questioners is seeking, but related by the giant trees.

Comment: @DonBoitnott if you mash Midworld and Call Him Joe together you've got Avatar.

Comment: @Organic Marble: The plot in Avatar is also very like the one in FernGully: The Last Rainforest.

Comment: Avatar had a plot? I just watched it for the best cgi ever done before and since. But truly I think all stories are inspired by previous stories,

Comment: This series was my immediate thought as well, pretty sure you are correct. The other outside alternative was a book also by ADF, one of the Flinx novels.

Comment: Another book with a giant forest is _Elven Star_, the second book of _The Death Gate Cycle_ by Margaret Weis & Tracy Hickman (1990).

Comment: Exploitative invaders/coloinsts with comparably hi-tech vs. peaceful, primitive and nature-dwelling natives seems to be a common trope throughout several genres, starting with Pocahontas, spanning Avatar and featuring in video games like Star Wars: Knight of the Old Republic, too. The distinct mark here was the description of the overburdening flora and well as the detailed description of the journey.

Comment: Midworld also has hexapodal life forms and a major character that becomes one with the trees.  I've often wondered when ADF will get a co-writing credit for Avatar.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common theme in SF Ursula K Le Guin wrote about the exact same thing in ["The Word for World is Forest"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Word_for_World_Is_Forest).

Kevin J Anderson created such a world in his ["Saga of the Seven Suns"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Saga_of_Seven_Suns) series
"The worldtrees of Theroc " were giant sapient trees miles high and were able to form spaceships.

> The most prominent human world aside from Earth is Theroc, a planet covered in semi-sentient worldtrees that is quietly independent from the Hansa. Theroc's "green priests" are able to commune with the trees and communicate telepathically across space when touching a treeling, making them indispensable for instantaneous communication across the galaxy.

There are many other examples.

Comment: It's worth noting that this id request already has an accepted answer but these match enough they're worth mentioning for someone with a similar request.